# I cannot get this white bar on top of the UIToolbar to dissapear?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitoolbar

Does anyone know how I can make my UI toolbar uniform in color. Whenever I add the "Information" button, I get a white bar on top. I need the UI Toolbar to be uniform. I have chosen the black/grey gradient color and this occurs. It also happens to every color except the default iPhone blue color UIToolbar color. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem; I need this to look cosmetically correct.

I have tried multiple things but they did not work...!

- I commented out everything but the UIToolbar To figure out where the white bar was.
- It seems to leave the top white line but if the navigation bar is black the UIToolbar shows the white bar.
- I tried setting the UIToolbar to transparent, that didn't work.
- I tried setting the color to black and that didn't work

Maybe the solution is to put it up there without the UIToolbar, but not sure, any help would be great. Please see the attached snapshot of what I am talking about for more detail.

Thanks.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Have you considered that you should be using a navigation bar on top instead of a toolbar?